# Run time 3134 error MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, insert-into

```
Private Sub AddItemButton_Click()
    Dim db As Database
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Dim Item As String
    Dim Rate As String
    Dim AltRate As String
    Dim Reason As String
    Dim ApporvedBy As String
    Dim Company As String
    Dim JobID As String

        Me.JobID2 = Me.JobID

        db.Execute "INSERT INTO InvItemsRecords (Item, Rate, AltRate, Reason, ApprovedBy, Company, JobID) VALUES ('" & Me.ItemAppendCBO & "', " & Me.RateAppend & ", " & Me.AltRateAppend & ", '" & Me.ReasonAppend & "', '" & Me.ApprovedByAppend & "', '" & Me.Customer & "', " & Me.JobID2 & ")"
        Me.AltRate2.Value = Null

End Sub
```

Comment: What's your problem? Please edit your question and share more details about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use string literals for your Queries

```
Dim sqlQuery As String
    sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO InvItemsRecords (Item, Rate, AltRate, Reason, ApprovedBy, " & _
               "Company, JobID) VALUES ('" & Me.ItemAppendCBO & "', " & Me.RateAppend & ", " & Me.AltRateAppend & ", '" & Me.ReasonAppend & "', '" & _
               Me.ApprovedByAppend & "', '" & Me.Customer & "', " & Me.JobID2 & ")"

db.Execute sqlQuery
```

It makes it a lot easier to debug

```
INSERT INTO InvItemsRecords (Item, Rate, AltRate, Reason, ApprovedBy, Company, JobID) 
 VALUES('Some Item', 100, 343, 'Reason A', 'John', 'Jane Doe', Null)
```

Chances are you are inadvertently passing 1 or more null values to non-nullable fields.  Also be careful about the data types.  You may need to use CStr(), CInt(), CLong, CDate() or ... to cast your data into the right format  If a field can be left blank us NZ().

NZ(Me.RateAppend, True)